# How can I connect the Psion 5mx email client to a secure email provider?

Tags: internet, serial, old-hardware-adaptation, psion

My Psion 5mx is connected to the Internet via the built in TCP stack, and serial cable to a raspberry pi running a PPP server.
The Psion message suite has an email client which will connect via POP3 and SMTP. I have added a plug in to also allow IMAP access.

There are few email providers who support unencrypted POP3 and SMTP access.

How could I connect the Psion email client to a secure SMTP or IMAP server?

Any solution is welcome, including another email client, an email server on the Pi end of the link or even, God forbid, Java.

Comment: I think the most viable solution is going to look like a pair of IMAP and SMTP daemons that proxy the Gmail box from the Pi. In which case the only ‘retro’ aspect of this setup is going to be that the client that connects to that proxy happens to be running on an old device…

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because while it is a Retrocomputing device, the real issue is encryption (or not) of email, which affects numerous devices, applications, etc. and not specifically RC.

Comment: I forget whether GMail supports the right kind of TLS initiation, but one option could be using `stunnel` to terminate the TLS at the Pi, leaving ports that, when connected to by the Psion using unencrypted protocols, connect to GMail using encrypted protocols. If it works, it'd probably be simpler than setting up a full-blown application-layer proxying setup. That's basically what I did to hack around Pidgin's lack of a "This TLS-only IRC server is supposed to be self-signed. Stop prompting for confirmation whenever the network hiccups" checkbox.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact there is a meta discussion about this at  https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/should-questions-about-connecting-older-hardware-to-modern-networks-be-in-scope

Comment: There are several possible solutions to this that involve only software running on the Psion, including alternative email clients and java SMTP proxies.

Comment: @MarkWilliams If there are such solutions, why don't you use one of them? Or is that just a hypothetical assumption? All somewhat realistic versions I can imagine would be due the RPi running some variation of the combination user3840170 suggests - which would, according to the meta post you linked clearly fall into the Off-Topic region.

Comment: @raffzahn the point of the meta post was to wonder if a question becomes off topic because some answers would be off topic. Just because I know of 2 possible answers (neither of which I have tried yet) doesn't mean they are the best answers. If I try them and they work, I will post them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connecting an email client without SSL to a modern server requires some sort of SSL gateway on another machine. For example, under Linux you might run a command like

`socat -v ssl:imap.gmail.com:993,end-close tcp4-listen:143,fork,reuseaddr &`

You can then point your email client at the gateway machine.

It turns out that stunnel (as suggested) will do all of the above, *and* add SMTP authorisation, making it an ideal solution.

I have found I can also use a Bluetooth connection to an Android phone and run stunnel there.